# Abstract sequence processing that involves state

Tags: c#, linq, sequence, state

Suppose I've a heterogeneous sequence of type that derives from `Animal` and `Food`.

That should transformed in instances of derived types: `Fed`, `NotFed` and `BadFed`.

```
var seq1 = new[] { new Fish(), new FishFood(), new Horse(), new DogFood(), new Dog() };
```

should be turned into

```
var seq2 = new [] {  new FishFed(), new HorseBadFed(), new DogNotFed() };
```

The logic is:

- if an `Animal` has proper food in the next element then a `XXXFed` instance is created;
- if there's a food in next elem. but is not good for that `Animal` -> `XXXBadFed`;
- otherwise if not food in the next element -> `XXXNotFed`.

Processing a sequence using conditional on next items it's less than trivial with iterations.

How can I use Linq or `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods to abstract sequence processing that involves state?

I know that `Aggregate` use an accumulator function for doing something similar; is this my case? Or better can use it to create a new sequence?

It's correct to use a [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) function to solve such problems without imperative code?

Comment: Some extension methods has overloads with index, so you can write something like this: `collection.Method((c, i) => do smth with c and collection[i+1])`.

Comment: @aush, overloads with index could be helpful, but I need to investigate further if enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first create pairs using the Zip function and then process the collection of pairs instead.

```
        var seq1 = new object[] { new Fish(), new FishFood(), new Horse(), new DogFood(), new Dog() };
        var count = seq1.Length;
        var foodSeq = seq1.Skip(1).Concat(new object[]{null});
        var dinnerPairs = seq1.Zip(foodSeq, (eater, food) => Tuple.Create(eater as Animal, food as Food)).Where(t => t.Item1 != null);
        var result = dinnerPairs.Select(t => t.Item1.Feed(t.Item2));
```

The Feed method on the Animal class would be overriden by each animal.
E.g. for dog it would return DogNotFed in case of null, DogFad in case of DogFood and DogBadFed otherwise.
If you have a strict naming convention, you could create those types dynamically using reflection.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Animal Feed(Food food);
}
```

EDIT: How I imagine the Feed method could resolve your logic using reflection, not tested though.

```
public Animal Feed(Food food)
    {
        var myType = this.GetType().FullName;
        if (food == null) return GetNewObject(myType + "NotFed") as Animal;
        if( food.GetType().FullName == myType+"Food") return GetNewObject(myType+"Fed") as Animal;
        return GetNewObject(myType+"BadFed") as Animal;
    }

    public static object GetNewObject(string typeName)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = Type.GetType(typeName);
            return t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the use of zip (that force me to investigate); but your sample don't take into account the variability of `seq1`. It directly solves the particular state of `seq1`, it's not general. Anyway it helped!

Comment: Actually it does, it takes only those pairs, who have an Animal as the first item. The part "eater as Animal" succeeds on all objects, the null objects are then filtered in the Where condition.

Comment: yes. But I mean it's tied to the knowledge you've of `seq1`. If `seq1` would be completely different? Sure it solves, if yes.. my mistake.

Comment: I will send you also the code using reflection to build the result types, you may need to change it if your types are in different namespaces or assemblies.

Comment: now it replies, completing the picture. The rest of code clarified. Interesting approach.

Comment: I confirm that your reply is really smart and complete and it answers. But going a bit further (not for performance reason: I was more concerned with readability & maintenability). I'd like something like F# Seq.Pairwise (I wrote my own https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/5200750); but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I've found also similar questions here but I'd try asking you. Can you suggested a good, mature and __well tested library__ with this kind of helpers on __IEnumerable<T> monad__?

Comment: +1, @Tomas Grosup, for suggestion. To be honest there's more but this one seems the best organized and clearly wrote (to first examination).

Answer (score -1):

In the real life, who it responsible for eating a food and getting sick or full or still staying hungry? It would be the animal itself.

So why not have an interface `IConsumeFood` implemented by an `Animal` type? Its method `Consume` would get some `food` and return the result of the food consumption.

Then you will be able to call this method on each animal, put all the food you have in there (the whole array) and let the animal decide what to eat, what not to eat and return you the appropriate result such as XXXFed, XXXNotFed, etc.

What I want you to avoid here is manipulations with type names or having tons of "ifs" around. 
It would be too dirty even for prototyping. Think of responsibilities and concerns, that's why we have OOP in the first place anyway :)